# How to add icon over an image where user tap the image in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is an imageview, now I want to add icons on image where user tab the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an overlay, just put two images (one for the icon) on top of each other using a `Grid` control and change the visibility of the overlay icon accordingly:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Key="background" ... />
    <Image x:Key="overlay" ... />
</Grid>
```